# IIS7 - Change physical path of all sites in server config

Tags: iis-7, migration, iis-7.5, applicationhost

Very close to killing myself, so please lend your ears and hands.

I've been trying to migrate an IIS7 webserver (rather large one), and so far am appalled by the state of msdeploy and using it for what I need to do. Enough on that, here's my current problem:

The server I'm migrating from has all the sites on a D:\ drive. It isn't possible for us to have a D:\ drive in the new environment, so I need to change all the site paths to C:.
I obviously do not want to do this for each site manually, so I thought to edit the paths in applicationHost.config. However, IIS doesn't seem to care one bit. All the paths are C:\, yet IIS still tries to reference D:.
When I look at site settings, it still says D:. Where in the WORLD is this value coming from?

It's on a 64-bit server, and I checked the OTHER applicationHost.config in \syswow64\, and that has magically changed to C:\ as well.

Any help, or perhaps a completely different way of migrating from D:\ to C:\ is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I assume you have restarted IIS, or is it set up to monitor config file changes?

Comment: Restarted IIS and system. How could I check if it monitors config changes?

Comment: Not exactly sure, but I know it's out there somewhere, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

"Fixed" it by copying applicationhost.config to a 2003 box, editing it there and copying back. Apparently 2008 "pretends" to save your file (i.e. it shows my changes when I open it in notepad) but read them from, either some cached version, or from another file elsewhere.